# Ошибка при создании массива: SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Tags: python, массивы

Добрый день, пытаюсь разделить один двумерный массив на три поменьше, но в последней строке вылезает ошибка "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call". Версия Python 3.6
Пожалуйста, подскажите как ее исправить

```
   N= len(matrix)
   M= len(matrix[0])
   n= (N) // 3 
   A=np.zeros((n,M))
   for i in range(n):
       for j in range(M):
           A(i,j)=matrix(i,j)
```

Comment: Может, вы имели в виду `A[i,j]`?

Comment: @andreymal Да, точно, в этом и была проблема, спасибо

Comment: `a = matrix[:n]` или `a,b,c = np.split(3)`

Answer (score 2):

Немножко не правильно:

```
A(i,j)=matrix(i,j)
```

А вот так правильно:

```
A[i,j]=matrix[i,j]
```